# My external USB Keyboard types wrong Keys on Macbook Pro

Tags: mac, keyboard, usb

i have an external USB Keyboard connected to my owc thunderbolt 3 docking station to my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017) running Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76) and get a complete wrong keymapping, like **qwertz** becomes **x4lz16**.

If I use a direct USB adapter this also happens. Keyboard Sharkoon / Skiller https://sharkoon.com/product/Skiller

[image: Settings Keyboard]

I can not find a button to update the keyboard when i am going to settings.

I have a Windows Boot Camp Partition, and running this in the same setup with only a restart not changing the hardware it runs completely as it should be.

I don't know how to solve this anymore and gave up after endless searches not finding me any similar problems. But maybe you know what up?

The Keyboard doesen't make any sense as i know, enter becomes ü..

I have another keyboard of this type and its the same problem. Another 2.ghz adapter keyboard by Logitech runs fine.

Comment: What are the make/manufacturer and model name/number of the two problematic keyboards?

Comment: Skiller / Sharkoon, idk of any model number but: https://sharkoon.com/product/Skiller

Comment: Does this answer your question? — https://superuser.com/questions/897626/getting-wrong-characters-on-sharkoon-skiller-pro-keyboard-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it: STRG+Shift+ALT+N with the wrong mapped keyboard